# How do I measure distance between objects?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Im coding a game with libGDX at the moment. The player should be able to perform attacks on enemies that are nearby.

My idea was to check the distance between the player and the enemy object and see if its in a specific range. If the player attacks and an enemy is in this specific range it gets damage.
The problem here is, that I need to create a new enemy class with every new enemy I add to the game.

Does someone have any ideas how I implement this mechanic in the best way?

Comment: You yourself just gave the answer to your question. Implement a class `Enemy`.

Comment: The easiest way to implement that is to track the center points of each entity (player and enemies) and potentially a bounding sphere around that center point for the enemies to roughly define where they are (a bounding box might be a better fit but calculations would be more complex). Then you basically define the attack range of your player, calculate the distance between the center points and if you're using bounding spheres subtract their radii from the distances. An enemy would then be hit if the resulting distance is lower than or equal to the attack range.

Comment: As for "new enemy class for every new enemy": the traditional way was to use inheritance, i.e. `abstract class Enemy`, `class Ork extends Enemy`, `class Troll extends Enemy` etc. This would limit you to a single hierarchy and get complex so composition might be the better option but given your assumed skill level I'd suggest starting with inheritance first.

Comment: I think I somehow found a way how to measure the distance. I added sensors to my player that have a different width and height. If an enemy collides with a sensor and the attack method gets called, it checks if the enemy is in a specific range (collides with a specific sensor). If that results true the attack makes damage. But until now that does only work in my head. I post the answer if I found a way to make it work.